# react native 0.71 syntax error when adding new components or screen

Tags: typescript, react-native, yarnpkg, react-native-cli

As you all guys know, React Native recently upgraded to version 0.71.0.

I started new project using CLI, but whenever I try to add new components or screens, I get a syntax error with the message "none of these file exists".

When I restart the app it's all okay until I need new component or screen.  I have no clue why this behaviour exists in 0.71.0 since I did not experience this issue in other versions. Maybe I missed something new. It is so annoying that I need to type `yarn start` every time I add new components.

I actually did not try anything to solve this problem because I have no idea where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. There is a note in react native blog post saying that after upgrading to React Native 0.71, we recommend removing @types/react-native from your package.json devDependencies. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save @types/react-native
```

just install this package.

Comment: Sadly it did not solve my problem. If I add new folder to project I need to restart the app, else I have syntax error.

Comment: React Native doesn't require @types/react-native package since v0.71 because it's now included by default. In fact, it's recommended remove that package if it's already in package.json : https://reactnative.dev/blog/2023/01/12/version-071